# How to perform udfs on multiple columns- dynamically

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 30 column like DPF_1,DPF_2,DPF_3......DPF_30 on which i need to apply data frames. All 30 columns datatype is `String`. 
My requirement is to convert  all "Na" values present in these 30 columns to "null"

I have tried below code but it is not dynamic.

```
def udf_A(x:StringType()):
    if x == "Na": return "null"
    else:return x
udf_B = udf(udf_A, StringType())

df.withColumn("DPF_1" udf_B("DPF_1"))
df.withColumn("DPF_2" udf_B("DPF_2"))
.
.
repeated till DPF_30
```

Now i want this process in dynamic way in pyspark/scala becouse later columns may increase with different column names.

Comment: You could always use a `regexp_replace` to convert `Na` to `null`

Comment: @philantrovert i have many other requirements. which can be done easily by using UDFS

Comment: So you're trying to convert Na to Null and do a bunch of other stuff with a single UDF?

Comment: @ philantrovert: yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code, hope this helps.

```
def udf_A(x:StringType()):
    if x == "Na": return "null"
    else:return x
udf_B = udf(udf_A, StringType())

import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

for c in df.dtypes:
    if "string" in c[1]:
        df=df.withColumn(c[0],udf_B(psf.col(c[0])))
df.show()
```

Here,
`df.dtypes` gives you array of tuples with column name and datatype

```
[('DPF_1', 'string'), ('DPF_2', 'string'), ('DPF_3', 'string')... ]
```

`c[0]` denotes the column name and `c[1]` denotes the data type which is `string` in your case.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. thank you, can you please explain what `dtypes `will actually do in the above process

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution in Scala:

```
// columns which you want to keep 
val colsToSelect : Seq[Column] = ???
// columns which are applied to UDF
val selectUDFs : Seq[Column] = (1 to 30).map(i => udf_B(col(s"DPF_$i")).as(s"DPF_$i"))

df.select((colsToSelect++selectUDFs):_*)
```

Comment: I think the columns are already called `DPF_1`. You can just do `df.columns.map(c => udf_B(c).as(c) )`

Comment: he does not mention wheter his dataframe has any other columns or not, therefore I don't want to assume anything

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert the *30 columns dataframe* to `na` `dataframe` and apply `replace` method as

```
df.na.replace(df.columns, Map("Na" -> "null"))
```

You will have replaced all `Na` strings to `null` string.

Comment: i have many other requirements. which can be done easily by using UDFS.

Comment: ok so for those requirements you can write udfs . Are the requirements the same for all columns? what are the other requirements?

Comment: yes requirements are same for all other columns. requirements are depends on data, these requirements can be handled mostly using If, else statements in UDFS.

Comment: Every time I see this `downvoters please do comment before you downvote` I am tempted to downovte ;) And without joking - we don't expect users to explain their votes, and definitely don't require that. Votes itself are self explanatory - down arrow has its `title` which is _This answer is not useful_ (for answers) or _This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_. In some cases (answer which is outright wrong, but sounds misleadingly right) it makes sense to provide explanation, but I wouldn't expect in general.

Comment: I can understand what you are saying @user8371915. But if the answer doesn't have a flaw why would somebody just downvote?

Comment: Usefulness is highly subjective and so are the votes (up or down the same).  Answer might be not useful because it is plain ugly, lacks explanation or is plain code dump, doesn't follow good practices, it is late and repeats the same thing as 10 other answers for the same question, shows not true effort, doesn't explain important caveats, are plain plagiarism and so on. Sometimes context is explained by following close votes or review queue feedback. If you get much more downvotes than you expect it is a hint that there is something missing according to unwritten and written community rules.

Comment: Unless it is because someone doesn't like you - but serial votes in either direction are automatically detected and reversed so no need to worry about it.

Comment: Oh, it is also possible that question (blatantly off-topic) is more a problem than the answer. In that case it might be just a cleaning effort so [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) can do its work, without trusted users casting delete votes.

Comment: Thank you @user8371915 for the explanation.

Comment: And a follow-up reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285081/8371915, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/8371915, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/8371915

Answer (score 1):

One approach, in Scala, would be to assemble a column list using a filter and traverse the list to transform the DataFrame using your UDF:

```
val cols = df.columns.filter(_.startsWith("DPF_"))

val df2 = cols.foldLeft( df )( (acc, c) => acc.withColumn(c, udf_B(df(c))) )
```